# Convert list of MultiPolygons and Polygons to a single MultiPolygon

Tags: python, shapely

How do I create in a generic manner a MultiPolygon from a list of MultiPolygon and Polygon objects?

```
a = MultiPolygon([Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 0)])])
b = Polygon([(0, 0), (2, 1), (1, 0)])
```

I wish to perform an operation that results in the following object:

```
MultiPolygon([Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 0)]) , Polygon([(0, 0), (2, 1), (1, 0)])])
```

I'm not looking to create a union, I just wish to iterate all the polygons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no functionality in Shapely that can make a list of polygons out of a list of both polygons and `MultiPolygon` objects. But you could write a simple [generator function](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generators) for that purpose:

```
from shapely.geometry import MultiPolygon, Polygon

a = MultiPolygon([Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 0)])])
b = Polygon([(0, 0), (2, 1), (1, 0)])
your_list = [a, b]


def to_polygons(geometries):
    for geometry in geometries:
        if isinstance(geometry, Polygon):
            yield geometry
        else:
            yield from geometry


result = MultiPolygon(to_polygons(your_list))
print(result.wkt)
# MULTIPOLYGON (((0 0, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0)), ((0 0, 2 1, 1 0, 0 0)))
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually ended up doing something similar myself. I think its strange though that such functionality does not exist, since there are a number of these Multi container types. And this should be a common problem.

Comment: Would it be a good idea to add assert type(geometries) in (Polygon,MultiPolygon) as the first line in the generator?

Comment: That's up to you. But I'd personally keep the function as simple as possible and, if needed, filter the incoming data outside.